# Service authentication in GKE similar to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

Is there a GKE service invocation authentication similar to OIDC tokens in Cloud Run? If not, how would one implement a similar functionality with GKE such that only authorized service accounts can invoke a service?

Comment: Are you looking to access the services from inside or outside the cluster?  Or both?

Comment: From the outside.

Comment: Did you look at using IAP with GKE Ingress?  It's not OIDC, but it is OAuth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, you have to implement GFE and IAM service by yourselves!!

In fact, you need a custom ingress controller that

- check the presence of a authorization header
- validate the authorization token
- Extract the principal from the token (the email)
- Check against an "authorization" database if that email is allowed or not.

So, you also need a service to administrate the authorization database (list, add, remove emails) maybe add more granular permissions.